# Solitaire rules for Catan Card Game?

Tags: house-rules, catan-card-game

I want to play the Catan Card Game more often than I can find someone with the patience to play it with me. I know there are some good solitaire rules for Settlers of Catan, but are there any for the Catan Card Game?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has been more than a year since I've asked this question. So, here are the rule modifications that I've play-tested. It seems to balance well, though I would like the game to go a little longer.

**Objective**: Get 12 victory points before 3 years are up.

- Remove the following cards from play: "Conflict" event, Merchant, Herb Woman, and all Attack cards.
- Shuffle Event cards without the "Year End" card. Pick 4 random cards from the shuffled event card deck and shuffle those 4 cards with the "Year End" card. Put this (5 card) stack on the bottom of the event card deck.
- 5 commerce points earns you the windmill token.
- 7 strength points earns you the knight token.
- When a tournament is rolled on the event die, if your number of tournament points is greater than or equal to the number rolled on the resource die, you get one extra resource of your choice.

Feel free to critique.

Answer (score 2):

Late reply is exceedingly late, but oh well. I tested these rules out and liked them; I also came up with some modifications I think add a little length and tension to the game.

**Objective:** Get 16 victory points before 4 years are up. *(N.B. this is theoretically extensible for use with add-ons et cetera- the 4VP/1yr formula seems to balance decently.)*

**Additional stipulations:**

- Do not remove the "Conflict" event.
- At the beginning of the game, roll the resource die 3 times, taking the top card of the appropriate development card pile each time (roll again on a 6). Place these 3 cards off to the side; they are the neutral player's hand, which can be affected by "Spy" cards or "Conflict" events (if you have earned the knight token).
- If, at the end of your turn (after you have refilled your hand if applicable), the neutral hand has less than 3 cards: roll to refill the neutral hand to 3 cards in the same way as at the beginning of the game.
- Every time the "Year End" card is drawn, repeat the process from the beginning of the game of shuffling 4 random cards along with it and placing them at the bottom of the pile. *(N.B. this is also theoretically extensible in both directions- it excludes 0-X events from the current year, where X is the number shuffled along with the "Year End" card, so game length will tend to increase as X decreases, and vice versa. However, this also reduces or intensifies the impact of luck respectively- X=4 is a good balance of all factors.)*
- When playing development cards, you must respect type: red developments can be played only on the additional spaces provided by a city. These may be built before or after green developments, but a city may only have 0-2 green developments and 0-2 red developments.
- A settlement (town or city) is considered "complete" when all of its development spaces are occupied (2 for a town, 4 for a city). Developments in a settlement confer their effects as normal (for example, knights contributing strength towards the knight token), but nothing in a settlement- including the settlement itself- is worth any VP until that settlement is complete. (This means a completed village is once again worth 0 VP upon upgrading to a city.)

**Possibly intended by original author but not explicitly mentioned:**

- Rolling a windmill on the event die while in possession of the windmill token entitles you to a free resource, as though you "stole" it from the neutral player
- The same goes for the "Merchant" cards, which essentially become free one-time 1:2 trades.

Again, feel free to critique.